# How to move the handles of a sequence via scripting?

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor

### There are the following commands:

#### create sequence editor

`bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor_create()`

#### add strip (name, filepath, channel, frame_start)

`bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_image("coolName", "path/db.png", 4, 1)`

Until now I have created a sequence on channel 4, starting at frame 1 like in the following picture:

[image]

I want to control the starting frame of the slider and the ending frame of this strip. How can I achieve this using blender script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the sequence object immediately when creating it:

```
seq = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_image("coolName", "somePath/img.PNG", 4, 1)
```

Then you can edit the `frame_final_start` and `frame_final_end` to edit the sequence start and finish, same as the handles:

```
seq.frame_final_start = 10
seq.frame_final_end   = 50
```

Comment: A list of other properties you can control: https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78c_release/bpy.types.Sequence.html#bpy.types.Sequence